# Why is my responsive navigation bar, made with Javascript, working only after refresh in iPhone browsers?

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile

If a user, using iPhone (actual devices), lands on my website for the first time the "hamburger menu" will not open the menu at all, and navbar will not appear on scrolldown. It seems to be working just fine on Android devices (except maybe Nexus 4 in portrait mode if we were to believe [responsinator](http://www.responsinator.com) ), and Win desktops.

The actual website's backend is made with Razor/ASP.NET but obviously I believe this is a pure frontend issue.

After a refresh it starts to work on Apple devices (well, iPhone) as well. And then sometimes stops working (once or twice it stopped working again, I believe).

Head (tried removing async and defer, did not work):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" async defer></script>
```

Here is HTML (with bad usage of h2 tag with logo image in it):

```
<div id="navigation-main">
    <h2 class="logo">
        <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/white-logo.png" alt="">
        </a>
    </h2>
    <div id="menu-icon">
        <span class="icon-menu-hamburguer"></span>
    </div>
    <nav id="menu-main">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#about-anchor">About us</a></li>
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#agenda-anchor">Agenda</a></li>
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#gallery-anchor">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#sponsors-anchor">Sponsors</a></li>
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#contact-anchor">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.html">Log in <img src="images/login_icon.png" alt=""></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
#navigation-main {
    min-height: 60px;
    z-index: 9;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

#navigation-main:active {
    background-color: #000000;
}

#navigation-main .logo {
    float: left;
}

#navigation-main .logo img {
    display: none;
}

#navigation-main nav {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}

#navigation-main nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

#navigation-main nav ul li {
    list-style: none
}

#navigation-main nav ul li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none
}

#navigation-main #menu-icon {
    display: none;
}

#navigation-main.active {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

#navigation-main.active img {
    display: inline-block;
}

#navigation-main.active #menu-icon {
    top: 10px;
}

#navigation-main.active .logo img {
    max-width: 50%;
}

#navigation-main.active nav li a {
    color: #FFFFFF
}

#navigation-main nav ul li img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #navigation-main .logo img {
        max-width: 80%
    }
    #navigation-main #menu-icon {
        padding: 18px 12px;
        margin: 2px 0;
        position: relative;
        top: 20px;
        display: block;
        float: right;
        z-index: 10;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #navigation-main #menu-icon .icon-menu-hamburguer {
        background: #ff0000;
        width: 30px;
        height: 4px;
        margin: 2px 0;
        display: block;
    }
    #navigation-main #menu-icon .icon-menu-hamburguer:after,
    #navigation-main #menu-icon .icon-menu-hamburguer:before {
        content: '';
        background: #ff0000;
        width: 30px;
        height: 4px;
        display: block;
        margin: 2px 0;
        position: relative;
    }
    #navigation-main #menu-icon .icon-menu-hamburguer:before {
        bottom: 8px;
    }
    #navigation-main #menu-icon .icon-menu-hamburguer:after {
        top: 2px;
    }
    #navigation-main nav {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #navigation-main nav.menu-active {
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    #navigation-main nav.menu-active ul {
        position: relative;
        top: 15%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    #navigation-main nav.menu-active a {
        padding: 8px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 1.75rem;
        display: block;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #navigation-main nav {
        float: right;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
    #navigation-main nav ul li,
    #navigation-main nav ul li img {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #navigation-main nav ul li a {
        padding: 0 5px;
        font-size: 0.9rem;
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
(function() {

    ////////// Sticky navbar and hamburger icon

    var headerScroll = getId('navigation-main'),
        scrollHeight = 250,
        menuIcon = getId('menu-icon'),
        menuMain = getId('menu-main'),
        classMenu = 'menu-active',
        classHeader = 'active';

    // Scroll
    window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollOn);

    function scrollOn() {
        animatedScroll(headerScroll, classHeader, scrollHeight);
    }

    // Responsive menu 
    menuIcon.onclick = function() {
        toggle(menuMain, classMenu);
    }

    menuMain.onclick = function() {
        toggle(menuMain, classMenu);
    }

    // Moving the element after scrolling
    function animatedScroll(element, classN, height) {
        y = pageYOffset;
        if (y > height) {
            element.className = classN;
        } else {
            element.className = '';
        }
    }

    // Change the element's class
    function toggle(element, classe) {
        element.className = element.className ? '' : classe;
    }

    // Return the element
    function getId(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }


    ////////// Sticky navbar and hamburger icon

    // Feature Test
    if ('querySelector' in document && 'addEventListener' in window && Array.prototype.forEach) {

        // Function to animate the scroll
        var smoothScroll = function(anchor, duration) {

            // Calculate how far and how fast to scroll
            var startLocation = window.pageYOffset;
            var endLocation = anchor.offsetTop;
            var distance = endLocation - startLocation;
            var increments = distance / (duration / 16);
            var stopAnimation;

            // Scroll the page by an increment, and check if it's time to stop
            var animateScroll = function() {
                window.scrollBy(0, increments);
                stopAnimation();
            };

            // If scrolling down
            if (increments >= 0) {
                // Stop animation when you reach the anchor OR the bottom of the page
                stopAnimation = function() {
                    var travelled = window.pageYOffset;
                    if ((travelled >= (endLocation - increments)) || ((window.innerHeight + travelled) >= document.body.offsetHeight)) {
                        clearInterval(runAnimation);
                    }
                };
            }
            // If scrolling up
            else {
                // Stop animation when you reach the anchor OR the top of the page
                stopAnimation = function() {
                    var travelled = window.pageYOffset;
                    if (travelled <= (endLocation || 0)) {
                        clearInterval(runAnimation);
                    }
                };
            }

            // Loop the animation function
            var runAnimation = setInterval(animateScroll, 16);

        };

        // Define smooth scroll links
        var scrollToggle = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll');

        // For each smooth scroll link
        [].forEach.call(scrollToggle, function(toggle) {

            // When the smooth scroll link is clicked
            toggle.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

                // Prevent the default link behavior
                e.preventDefault();

                // Get anchor link and calculate distance from the top
                var dataID = toggle.getAttribute('href');
                var dataTarget = document.querySelector(dataID);
                var dataSpeed = toggle.getAttribute('data-speed');

                // If the anchor exists
                if (dataTarget) {
                    // Scroll to the anchor
                    smoothScroll(dataTarget, dataSpeed || 500);
                }

            }, false);
        });
    }
})();
```

And here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KloKlo/55yrzg07/1/).

If it's touchstart/onclick issue why does it work after the refresh? Should I remove IFFE? Should I put script tag at the end of the page?

What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the line in the header was an issue.I have removed "async" and the navigation menu started working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" async defer></script>
```

changed to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer></script>
```